# Specify an ip for an url in a Jenkins Job

Tags: unix, dns, jenkins, ip, host

I have the following situation.

The webapp in my company is deployed to several environments before reaching live. Every testing environment is called qa-X and has a different IP Address. What I would like to do is to specify in the jenkins job "test app in qa-x" the app's IP for the x environment so that my tests start running only knowing the apps url.

Jenkins itself is outside the qa-x environments.

I have been looking around for solutions but all of them destroy the other tests of qa-X. For instance, changing /etc/hosts, or changing the dns server. What would be great is that I can specify in that job only the ip as a config parameter and that that definition remains local.

Any thoughts/ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your query correctly, you should look into creating a [Parameterized build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) which would expose an environment variable with the desired server IP, which your test script could consume.